# What to use instead of "this" in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Here's my code:

```
if ($(this.el).find('.select-picture').is(':checked')) {
    var source = $(this).parent().prev().attr('src');
    document.cookie = "imagePath=" + source;
    var myCookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)imagePath\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
    console.log(myCookie);
}
```

I have a class .select-picture and I'm looking for it's parent's previous element and I want to perform an action on it (save the image path to a cookie). The code works nicely when put between  tags in html document, but when putting it in Backbone's view the console returns "undefined".

I'm almost sure it's because "this" in Backbone is not what "this" was in its previous place, but I don't know how to change it to make it work.

Could somebody help me?

EDIT - this is HTML:

```
 <div class="img-holder">
     <img src="images/picture.jpg" class="img-responsive top-img choose-img"/>
     <form>
         <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="select-picture">
      </form>
 </div>
 <div class="img-holder">
      <img src="images/picture2.jpg" class="img-responsive choose-img"/>
      <form>
         <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="select-picture">
      </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: `console.log(this)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understanding scope and context in javascript.
I suppose your template is something like this :

```
<script id="template_id" type="text/template">
<div>

    <% _.each(images, function(image){ %>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="<%= image.src %>" />
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <input class="select-picture" name="image[<%= image.uid %>]['is_checked']" type="checkbox" />          
            <input name="image[<%= image.uid %>]['quantity']" type="text" />  
        </div>
      <div> 
    <% }); %>
</div>
</script>
```

In you Backbone View you can do something like that :

```
Backbone.View.extend({

   el : $('#template_id'),

   function onChecked(){
      /* 
       *  this.$el refer to #template_id element.
       */
      this.$el.find('.select-picture:checked').each(function(index){
           /* 
            * Now this referer to the current context.  
            */
           var source = $(this).parent().prev().attr('src');
           document.cookie = "imagePath=" + source;
           var myCookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)imagePath\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
           console.log(myCookie);
      })
   },
});
```

Take a look at :

- http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript
- http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view
- http://underscorejs.org/#bind

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at the resources you suggested, for now it works just the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**this** refer to view(may be) view object here, not the element
try finding the element dirctly if it belongs to view's template

```
  if ($(this.el).find('.select-picture').is(':checked')) {
        var source = this.$('.select-picture').parent().prev().attr('src');
        document.cookie = "imagePath=" + source;
        var myCookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)imagePath\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
        console.log(myCookie);
    }
```

Comment: It applies to the first .select-picture only, no matter which one I click. Anyway, it's better than it was, but still not working the way it should.

Comment: can you be more specific what are trying to achieve! will the user click on the select picture element or you should check all of the elements on click of a button.

Comment: I edited the question - some html added. When clicking on a radio button with the class .select-picture, I want to save the path to the image right before it - hence the .parent().prev(). WIth your solution it saves the path to the first picture only, no matter which radio button I click. My original code works well outside of Backbone.

Comment: do you have any events, to know when the user checked the radio button?

Comment: yes, this is the code in events: `"change .select-picture": "selectExisting"` and the code above is wrapped in `selectExisting : function() {.....}`